# Bulk replace multiple variables in multiple files at once

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, find, python

Example: I have 40 different variables like `$VAR` in 100 `.txt` files which are located in `/home/user/EXAMPLE/`. How do I replace all variables in the 100 files?

To tell the system what the variables are it would be nice to use a file like `.csv` or a `.txt` file with a delimiter. Example:

```
$VAR=x 
$VAR2=xx
$VAR3=xxx
```

Any idea how to do this bulk editing?

Comment: replace what? with what? Can you show an example input file and the corresponding output?

Comment: There's several different things that might mean and several different possible solutions for each meaning. Please [edit] your quetsion to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input (that uses realistic names and values not always VARN and xxx) and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the problem into two parts:

1. Iterate across the files
2. Apply the substitution to a file

If you are in the `EXAMPLE` directory you can loop across all the files like this

```
for file in *.txt
do
    echo "Considering file $file"
done
```

To substitute a set of variables, ideally none would clash with an existing shell variable (e.g. `$PATH` or `$HOME`) you could then use `envsubst`.

Create a file `variables.sh` with each line in this format:

```
export varname=value
export anothername='a longer value'
```

Then you can use this code to substitute variables such as `$varname` and `$anothername` into a named file:

```
( . variables.sh; envsubst ) <"$file" >"$file.tmp" &&
    mv -f "$file.tmp" "$file"
```

Rolling these together:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    echo "Considering file $file"
    ( . variables.sh; envsubst ) <"$file" >"$file.tmp" &&
        mv -f "$file.tmp" "$file"
done
```